# Thymeleaf inside [if mso]

Tags: java, css, spring, thymeleaf

I am working on an email template using spring thymeleaf. I need to include a check for MS-outlook [if mso] inside my template. I need to set a variable inside the block. I was wondering if there is a way to do that.

```
<!--[if mso]><p style="line-height:0;margin:0;">&nbsp;</p><v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" th:href="@{|${baseUrl}/#/signup?email=${registrationRequest.email}&amp;key=${registrationRequest.registrationToken}|}" style="width:124px" arcsize="8%" strokecolor="#339561" filled="t"><v:fill type="gradient" angle="180" color="#44C781" color2="#3AA96E"></v:fill><v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:t" inset="0px,11px,0px,11px"><center style="font-size:14px;line-height:24px;color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Tahoma,sans-serif;font-weight:bold;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;mso-text-raise:4px">Register</center></v:textbox></v:roundrect><![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

You could supply the whole MS Outlook specific block of HTML code, including the special start and end comments, via a variable but doing that removes the ability for Thymeleaf to perform variable substitution within that block.

Preserving variable substitution can be achieved very easily by having two variables instead of one: a start MSO comment variable and an end MSO comment variable - these generate just the start MSO and end MSO comments respectively.

Leave the Outlook specific code inside your template and wrap it in the start/end markers like this:

```
<div th:remove="tag" th:utext="${startMsoComment}"></div>  

<!-- Outlook specific markup -->
... variable substitution works here
<p style="line-height:0;margin:0;">&nbsp;</p>
<v:roundrect 
... variable substitution works here
</v:roundrect>
... variable substitution works here

<div th:remove="tag" th:utext="${endMsoComment}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by moving the whole block of [if mso] inside server side. I appended the required variables and rendered the block in the template using

```
<div th:remove="tag" th:utext="${msoTemplate}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way in my opinion to have the if mso pseudo-comments is to use th:block

```
<th:block th:utext="${ifgtemso9}"></th:block>
.. your html ...
<th:block th:utext="${endif}"></th:block>
```

and when you set your model or context you do something like this:

```
ctxEmail.setVariable("ifgtemso9","<!--[if gte mso 9]>");
ctxEmail.setVariable("ifnotmso15comment","<!--[if !mso 15]><!-->");
ctxEmail.setVariable("endif","<!--<![endif]-->");
ctxEmail.setVariable("endif_end","<![endif]-->");
```

And then you use the corresponding variable in a utext.

(I am calling thymeleaf with a context directly here, but I am sure you know how you can set model parameters yourself)